# zend framework flash messanger message and redirect

Tags: zend-framework, action, helper, flash-message

So i am creating a project using zend-framwork and i am trying to implement the flash messenger helper but i cant find any good practice to implement it. 
What i need is to use the flash messenger to send a message and redirect, while the message will appear directly in a specific place in the layout.phtml.
I know that for the redirector i can do that:

```
$redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
$redirector->gotoUrl('/my-controller/my-action/param1/test/param2/test2')
               ->redirectAndExit();'
```

What can i do to the flash messanger to make it work ? and what is the best practice for that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your controller

```
public function init()
{
$messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();
if(!empty($messages))
$this->_helper->layout->getView()->message = $messages[0];
}
```

in your layout.phtml

```
    <!-- Global notification handling to use call flashMessenger action helper -->
    <?php if(isset($this->message)) :?>
    <div class="notification">

    <?php echo $this->message ;?>

    </div>    
 <?php endif;?>
```

Then whenever you want to use it

```
public function loginAction()
{
$this->_helper->flashMessenger('Login is success');
$this->_helper->redirector('home');
}
```

Almost every-time you will be redirecting after using flashMessenger.

Comment: This will only gets one flash message at a time..you cannot iterate

Comment: I have never encounter any need of more then one message .

Comment: this worked fine for now, But i have one question why the auto complete in net beans doesn't show the auto complete when i am using the _helper and how can i make to do so ??

Comment: @dorinaji Since helper uses php magic function __call hence its not possible to determine the name of helper  .But Zend Studio (IDE) do show auto complete for helpers since its aware of ZF structure . Its one of the important features for which I use Zend Studio myself.

Answer (score 2):

How to use flash messenger in Zend
suppose you have an action called 'foo'

```
public function fooAction(){

 $flashMessenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
 //some codes
 $flashMessenger->addMessage(array('error' => 'This is an error message'));
$this->_redirect('/someothercontroller/bar');

}
//someothercontroller/barAction
public function barAction(){

$flashMessenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
 $this->view->flashmsgs = $flashMessenger->getMessages();  //pass it to view 

}
```

In your view part

```
<?php if(isset($this->flashmsgs)) { ?>
                 <?php foreach($this->flashmsgs as $msg){ 
                       foreach ($msg as $key=>$diserrors) {
                        if($key=="error"){?>
      //do wat you want with your message
<?php } } }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work inside an Controller

```
/**
 * @var Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger
 */
protected $flashMessenger = null;


/**
 * initalize flash messenger
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function init() 
{
    $this->flashMessenger = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger;
}

/**
 * Action wich is redirectin.. and sets message
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function actiononeAction()
{
    $this->flashMessenger->addMessage('FLY HiGH BiRD!');
    $this->_redirect('/whatever/url/in/your/project');
}

/**
 * display messages from messenger
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function displayAction()
{
    $myMessages = $this->flashMessenger->getMessages();
    $this->view->messages = $myMessages;
}
```

Comment: Controllers should not really keep state; therefore, creating variables for them is not good practice. Instead, simply use `$this->_helper->flashMessenger`, or if bored of typing longhand, assign it per action as `$flashMessenger = $this->_helper->flashMessenger`. Use the request object for state in a request if you aren't using a model.